# In java8, how to set the global value in the lambdas foreach block?

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

```
    public void test(){
       String x;
       List<String> list=Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");

       list.forEach(n->{
          if(n.equals("d"))
            x="match the value";
       });
    }
```

1.Like the code above, I want to set the value of a variable beside the foreach block, can it works?

2.And why?

3.And the foreach iterator is in order or disorder?

4.I think the lamdas foreach block is cool and simple for iterator,but this is really a complicated  thing to do rather than the same work in java 7 or before.

Comment: your loop can be replaced (for example) by `if (list.stream().filter("d"::equals).findAny().isPresent()) x = "match the value";`. In most situations, there will be a way to write the code without having to manipulate external variables.

Comment: @assylias: `if(list.stream().anyMatch("d"::equals)) …` or `if(list.contains("d")) …`

Comment: @Holger Argh - I always forget about that method (anyMatch) and yes indeed, contains even better. Thanks!

Comment: just use the good old for-each.

Comment: @All  Thanks. In fact , I want to solve this Problem. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561029/in-java8-how-to-set-the-global-value-in-the-lambdas-foreach-block-plus)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could, of course, "make the outer value mutable" via a trick:

```
public void test() {
    String[] x = new String[1];
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");

    list.forEach(n -> {
        if (n.equals("d"))
            x[0] = "match the value";
    });
}
```

Get ready for a beating by the functional purist on the team, though. Much nicer, however, is to use a more functional approach ([similar to Sleiman's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32522082/521799)):

```
public void test() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
    String x = list.stream()
                   .filter("d"::equals)
                   .findAny()
                   .map(v -> "match the value")
                   .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote that one. Inventing a highly complicated functional construct for something that can be done straightforward with a traditional loop can't be recommended.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff: Suit yourself.

Answer (score 9):

1. No you can't do it. (Although you should have tried it yourself)
2. Because variables used within anonymous inner classes and lambda expression have to be `effectively final`.
3. you can achieve the same more concisely using `filter` and `map`.

   ```
   Optional<String> d = list.stream()
                            .filter(c -> c.equals("d"))
                            .findFirst()
                            .map(c -> "match the value");
   ```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to already provided idiomatic examples, another hack would be to use AtomicReference, but I would only recommend it if you do need 'forEach' and prefer something more readable than true-functional variant:

```
public void test(){
    AtomicReference<String> x = new AtomicReference<>();
    List<String> list= Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");

    list.forEach(n->{
        if(n.equals("d"))
            x.set("match the value");
    });
}
```

Comment: Upvoted just for `AtomicReference` though I wouldn't recommend it for foreach. Instead this approach is makes sense if used for a parallelstream.

Answer (score 6):

As it's already explained, you cannot modify the local variable of the outer method from the lambda body (as well as from the anonymous class body). My advice is don't try to use lambdas when they are completely unnecessary. Your problem can be solved like this:

```
public void test(){
   String x;
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
   if(list.contains("d"))
       x = "match the value";
}
```

In general lambdas are friends with functional programming where you rarely have mutable variables (every variable is assigned only once). If you use lambdas, but continue thinking in imperative style you will always have such problems.

Comment: As a side note, your code indeed matches the OP’s code in that `x` is completely useless afterwards as might not be assigned.