# How to change the local variable of the outer method in the lambdas foreach block?

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

Not for-each block:

```
public void cleanup4(){
    long timestamp = Instant.now().minus(90l, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .toEpochMilli();
    String cql = "SELECT * FROM usertoken";
    ResultSet rs = CassandraTools.getInstance().execute(cql,ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
    CassandraConverter cassandraConverter=new MappingCassandraConverter();
    CassandraConverterRowCallback<UserTokenCassandra> callback= new CassandraConverterRowCallback<UserTokenCassandra>(cassandraConverter, UserTokenCassandra.class);
    UserTokenCassandra utc = null;
    Iterator<Row> iterator = rs.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = iterator.next();
        utc=callback.doWith(row);
        log.info("{}", utc);
        log.info("记录的时间为：{}",
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(utc.getExpireTime()));
        if (timestamp > utc.getExpireTime()) {
            // repository.delete(n);
        }
    }
}
```

For-each block:

```
public void cleanup4(){
    long timestamp = Instant.now().minus(90l, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .toEpochMilli();
    String cql = "SELECT * FROM usertoken";
    ResultSet rs = CassandraTools.getInstance().execute(cql,ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
    CassandraConverter cassandraConverter=new MappingCassandraConverter();
    CassandraConverterRowCallback<UserTokenCassandra> callback= new CassandraConverterRowCallback<UserTokenCassandra>(cassandraConverter, UserTokenCassandra.class);
    rs.forEach(usertoken->{
        UserTokenCassandra utc = null;
        log.info("{}", utc);
        log.info("The Time：{}",
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(utc.getExpireTime()));
        if (timestamp > utc.getExpireTime()) {
            // repository.delete(utc);
        }
    });
}
```

1.The  for-each block seems generate a lot no use reference of UserTokenCassandra .. And  are  these garbage?
2.So How to write this code?

Comment: The other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561029/in-java8-how-to-set-the-global-value-in-the-lambdas-foreach-block-plus)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Could you clarify what do you expect of the code and what is currently wrong with it?

Comment: The difference is the UserTokenCassandra ,it's a java object. If I put it in the for each block ,it would like to produce more pointer and reference in JVM. I think it is not pure. So how could I put the UserTokenCassandra out side the block?

Comment: `UserTokenCassandra` is populated by `callback.doWith(row);` for each result row. It seems appropriate to place this delaration inside the for each loop. Why do you think this would have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: Your entire question is based around nonsense. Whether you declare a local variable inside or outside the loop has no impact on the code at all. Besides that, the recommended code style is to *minimize* the scope of variables.

Comment: @Holger The recommended code style is to minimize the scope of variables? Not to minimize the lifestyle of variables?  And in my mind ,the second code style which the variable is definated in the block is much bigger than the former one for longer lifetime of the variable.

Comment: Sorry, definated should change to defined.

Comment: You may say about the “lifestyle of variables” whatever you want. When it comes to the *lifetime* of variables, it’s hard to image how anyone can think that extending the scope of a variable may reduce its lifetime. In this universe, the lifetime and scope of variables are congruent.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the outer method local variable from within the lambda body. Here you don't need the `forEach`. As `ResultSet` [implements `Iterable`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html), you can use enhanced `for` loop instead:

```
for(Row row : rs) {
    utc=callback.doWith(row);
    log.info("{}", utc);
    log.info("记录的时间为：{}",
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(utc.getExpireTime()));
    if (timestamp > utc.getExpireTime()) {
        // repository.delete(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: At the end,I solve my problem this way..The Collection.forEach method seems not to be suitable for this situation.