# Setting a boolean flag inside Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm wondering what the best practices are for setting a boolean flag value from a java stream. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
    boolean flag = false;
    List<Integer> newList = list.stream()
                                //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
                                .filter(i -> {
                                    if(condition(i)){
                                        flag = true;
                                    }
                                    return condition(i);
                                })
                                //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //do some work with the new list and the flag
```

However, this goes against the language restriction "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final". There are a few solutions I can think of but I'm not sure which is best. This first solution I have is adding elements that match `condition` to a list and checking `List::isEmpty`. One could also wrap `flag` in an `AtomicReference`.

Note that my question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521972/in-java8-how-to-set-the-global-value-in-the-lambdas-foreach-block), but I'm trying to extract a boolean value in the end rather than setting a variable.

Comment: It's not advice, it's a language restriction.

Comment: *One could also wrap the `flag` in an `AtomicReference`.*  Or `AtomicBoolean`?

Comment: Your first solution looks perfectly fine: checking isEmpty seems like the right approach.

Comment: fixed it @shmosel

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't think he's talking about the result list, which goes through additional transformations.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can't check `newList.isEmpty()` since there are many other stream operations applied before and after. I would have to make a new list specifically for the condition. This is one of the possible solutions I mention.

Comment: you can use `final boolean[] flagTarget = new boolean[1];` if you want to avoid the overhead of an atomic.

Comment: Anyone reading this post should not consider this to be a "good idea" i.e. having a side effect from a `filter()`. The OP should post more code because the problem can probably be solved more elegantly and keeping in line with functional programming best practices (e.g. using `findAny()`)

Comment: Also don't for get that `for (Integer value : list) {...}` still works fine in Java 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don’t taint your task of producing the `newList` with an entirely unrelated task. Just use

```
boolean flag = list.stream().anyMatch(i -> condition(i));
```

followed by the other stream code.

There are two typical objections

1. But this is iterating twice.

   Yes, it is, but who says that iterating an `ArrayList` twice is a problem? Don’t try to avoid multiple stream operations, unless you know that you really have an expensive-to-traverse stream source, like an external file. If you have such an expensive source, it might still be easier to collect the elements into a collection first, which you can traverse twice.
2. But it’s evaluating `condition(…)` more than once.

   Well, actually it’s evaluating it less than you original code

   ```
   .filter(i -> {
       if(condition(i)){
           flag = true;
       }
       return condition(i);
   })
   ```

   as `anyMatch` stops at the first match, while you original predicate evaluates `condition(i)` twice per element, unconditionally.

---

If you have several intermediate steps preceding the condition, you may collect into an intermediate `List` like

```
List<Integer> intermediate = list.stream()
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .filter(i -> condition(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
boolean flag = !intermediate.isEmpty();
List<Integer> newList = intermediate.stream()
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but more than often, the intermediate step aren’t as expensive at it might seem at the first glance. The performance characteristics of similar intermediate steps may vary in different stream operations, depending of the actual terminal operation. So it might still work sufficiently doing these steps on-the-fly:

```
boolean flag = list.stream()
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .anyMatch(i -> condition(i));
List<Integer> newList = list.stream()
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .filter(i -> condition(i))
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you worry about the code duplication itself, you can still put the common code into a stream returning utility method.

Only in very rare cases, it pays off to go into the lowlevel API and peek into the Stream like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45180118/2711488). And if you do so, you shouldn’t go the route of an `Iterator` which will loose meta information about the contents, but use a `Spliterator`:

```
Spliterator<Integer> sp = list.stream()
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .filter(i -> condition(i))
    .spliterator();
Stream.Builder<Integer> first = Stream.builder();
boolean flag = sp.tryAdvance(first);
List<Integer> newList = Stream.concat(first.build(), StreamSupport.stream(sp, false))
    //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that in all of these cases, you could short-cut if `flag` is `false`, as the result can only be an empty list then:

```
List<Integer> newList = !flag? Collections.emptyList():
/*
   subsequent stream operation
 */;
```

Comment: I added another comment line to the streaming code that affects your answer. The condition is being evaluated in the middle of the processing chain, instead of at the beginning as the posted code originally read.

Comment: Eh, even so.  Store the intermediate filtered result in an intermediate List, check if it's empty, and continue the stream from that List.

Comment: That makes sense. @Holger I'll accept if you update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** (based on [Holger's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173021/setting-a-boolean-flag-inside-java-8-stream/45180118#comment77335374_45180118))

*I'm letting this answer here only for historical purposes ;) This was my attempt to solve the problem with an `Iterator`, though a `Spliterator` is much better. This answer is not 100% wrong, however the characteristics of the spliterator that backs the stream (i.e. `SIZED`, `ORDERED`, etc) are lost when the stream is transformed to an `Iterator`. Please see [Holger's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173513/1876620) for the best approach, as long as other alternatives and a brief discussion about whether this is worth the effort.*

---

If you need to know whether there has been a match on a filter condition *in the middle* of a stream pipeline, you might want to consider converting the stream to an `Iterator`, check if the iterator has a next element, store that value as your flag, then create a new stream from the iterator and finally go on with the stream pipeline.

In code:

```
Iterator<Whatever> iterator = list.stream()
    // many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .filter(i -> condition(i))
    .iterator();

boolean flag = iterator.hasNext();
```

Then, create a new `Stream` from the iterator:

```
Stream<Whatever> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
        iterator, 
        Spliterator.NONNULL), // maybe Spliterator.ORDERED?
    false);
```

And finally go on with the stream pipeline:

```
List<Integer> newList = stream
    // many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you have `newList` and `flag` to work with.

Comment: I know you don't agree with that, but I would just put that into a `CHM` as a *side-effect*...

Comment: I have incorporated a similar approach into my answer, as an alternative, however, it uses `Spliterator` instead of `Iterator`, so there’s no guesswork about the appropriate characteristics needed, also, it doesn’t loose the size estimate if there is one.

Comment: @Eugene I know, I know... :D

Comment: @Holger You did it nice with the `Spliterator`. I didn't use it because `tryAdvance` also consumes the first element, so I thought `Iterator` would be better in this case. As it's clear now, I was obviously wrong and `Spliterator` is much better. I didn't think of the `Stream.Builder` and `Stream.concat` approach, that's really clever.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the boolean flag separately

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> newList = list.stream()
                            .filter(i -> condition(i))
                            //many other filters, flatmaps, etc...
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean flag = list.stream()
                     .filter(i -> condition(i))
                     .findAny()
                     .isPresent();
```

Comment: I added another comment line to the streaming code that affects your answer. The condition is being evaluated in the middle of the processing chain, instead of at the beginning as the posted code originally read.